# Knockout Binding Always Returns Empty String

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

OK, I have discovered the problem, but not the solution. If I use the following code instead, then things work correctly:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="timestamp" id="option1" class="btn btn-default" value="L" data-bind="checked: chosenCompare, event: {click: conditionChange}">L</input>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="timestamp" id="option2" class="btn btn-default" value="E" data-bind="checked: chosenCompare, event: {click: conditionChange}">E</input>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="timestamp" id="option3" class="btn btn-default" value="M" data-bind="checked: chosenCompare, event: {click: conditionChange}">M</input>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically all I have done is removed the Bootstrap/Conquer look-and-feel, so there is a problem with the interaction between Bootstrap/Conquer and Knockout.

Original post below...

I have the following template fragment that Knockout uses, along with some Bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <select class="form-control"
          data-bind="options: $parent.availableChannels(),
            optionsCaption: 'Choose one...',
            value: chosenChannel, event: {change: $parent.conditionChange}"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" name="timestamp" id="option1" class="btn btn-default" value = "L" data-bind="value: chosenCompare, event: {change: $parent.conditionChange}">L</input>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" name="timestamp" id="option2" class="btn btn-default" value = "E" data-bind="value: chosenCompare, event: {change: $parent.conditionChange}">E</input>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" name="timestamp" id="option3" class="btn btn-default" value = "M" data-bind="value: chosenCompare, event: {change: $parent.conditionChange}">M</input>
      </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">                      
    <input id="number-picker" type="text" value="" name="number-picker" style="text-align: center" data-bind="value: chosenNumber, event: {change: $parent.conditionChange}" >
</div>

VM.model.channelCondition = function channelCondition(data) {
  var o = this
  o.base = VM.model.condition;
  o.base(data);
  o.chosenChannel = ko.observable();
  o.chosenCompare = ko.observable();
  o.chosenNumber = ko.observable();
  o.isReady = function() {
    return o.chosenChannel() !== undefined && o.chosenCompare() !== undefined && o.chosenNumber() !== undefined;
  }
}

VM.conditionChange = function(data, event) {
  console.log("conditionChange data:\n\t ", data);
  console.log("conditionChange event:\n\t ", event);
  console.log("chosenChannel = ", data.chosenChannel());
  console.log("chosenCompare = '" + data.chosenCompare() + "'");
  console.log("chosenNumber = ", data.chosenNumber());
  console.log("isReady() = ", data.isReady());
  return true;
}
```

My bindings for chosenChannel and chosenNumber work fine, but I have been trying for hours to get knockout to bind the radio buttons to chosenCompare, with no luck.

Before I click any of the radio buttons, chosenCompare is bound to undefined, as I would expect. When I click one of the radio buttons, then conditionChange is called, and the value of chosenCompare() changes from undefined to '' (the empty string).

I have tried using the checked binding, but that has no effect at all, at least the value binding changes something.

Am I just missing something simple here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `checked` binding with radio buttons, and bind to the `click` event instead of the `change` event or `chosenCompare()` will return the previous value instead of the current one.  But you'll need to make sure your `conditionChange` method returns `true` so that the default click handler still runs.

```js
var viewModel = {
  chosenCompare: ko.observable(),
  conditionChange: function() {
    alert('chosenCompare is now: ' + viewModel.chosenCompare());
    return true;
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="timestamp" id="option1" class="btn btn-default" value="L" data-bind="checked: chosenCompare, event: {click: conditionChange}">L</input>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="timestamp" id="option2" class="btn btn-default" value="E" data-bind="checked: chosenCompare, event: {click: conditionChange}">E</input>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="timestamp" id="option3" class="btn btn-default" value="M" data-bind="checked: chosenCompare, event: {click: conditionChange}">M</input>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, I can see that your example works. However, for me it still does not work. It is interesting to note that when I use the 'click' event, conditionChange does not get called, but when I use the 'change' event, conditionChange does get called. I suspect there is something deeper going on that is causing this to fail.

Comment: Something else that is interesting. I was using Knockout 3.1.0, but when I change to Knockout 3.2.0 there is different behavior. In 3.2.0 the value of chosenCompare never changes.

Comment: @EricKolotyluk Hmm...could you edit your question to show how you're creating your ko view model?

Comment: Sure, I have updated the example. FYI, chosenChannel and chosenNumber are working perfectly.

Comment: Do you have any more ideas about what my problem may be with this binding?

Comment: @EricKolotyluk I think you'd have to post a snippet/fiddle that reproduces the problem to get more help on this.

Comment: OK, I'll see what I can do to create something self contained.